# How to fix [Errno13] permission denied when trying to read excel file?

Tags: python, excel

I tried the following code to be able to read an excel file from my personal computer.

```
import xlrd

book = xlrd.open_workbook('C:\\Users\eline\Documents\***\***\Python', 'Example 1.xlsx')
```

But I am getting the error 'Permission denied'. I am using windows and if I look at the properties of the directory and look at the 'Security' tab I have three groups/users and all three have permissions for all the authorities, except for the last option which is called 'special authorities' (as far as I know I do not need this authority to read the excel file in Python).

I have no idea how to fix this error. Furthermore, I do not have the Excel file open on my computer when running the simulation.

I really hope someone can help me to fix this error.

Comment: Could you please post the full stack of the exception you get? Also could you please try running your script from an elevated command prompt?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
book = xlrd.open_workbook('C:\\Users\eline\Documents\***\***\Python', 'Example 1.xlsx')
```

You cannot give path like this to xlrd. path need to be single string.

If you insist you can use `os` module

```
import os
book = xlrd.open_workbook(os.path.join('C:\\Users\eline\Documents\***\***\Python', 'Example 1.xlsx'))
```

`[Errno13] permission denied` in your case is happening because you want to read folder like a file which is not allowed.

Comment: Wow, I feel amazingly stupid. it works now. Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 14):

Sometimes, it is because you try to read the Excel file while it is opened. Close the file in Excel and you are good to go.

Comment: omg. debugging is really hurt when you have to do this every dang time. I do about 50-100 open and closing a day. can you imagine!!

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this situation also while reading an Excel file into a data frame.  To me it appears that it is a Python and/or Excel bug which we should probably not hide by using os.path.join even if that solves the problem.  My situation involved an excel spreadsheet that links cells to another CSV file.  If this excel file is freshly opened and open when I try to read it in python, it fails.

Python reads it correctly if I do an unnecessary save of the open Excel file.